# My PHP Store Locator Is Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

I built a simple store locator and I setup a custom search engine to find stores by name, zip code, etc, and it works.

Now, I'm trying to find stores by address and return the nearest locations and distance using the haversine formula. Below is my code. Where am I going wrong?

When I pass the `$distance` variable to the `mysqli_query()` it tells me that it is expecting an integer. I'm probably way off.

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Store Locator</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <label for="search">Enter Store Name</label></br>
            <input type="text" name="search" value="">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" name="address" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $search = $_POST['search'];
                $query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE zip_code LIKE '%$search%' ";
                $distance = "
                    SELECT id, 
                           (3959 * acos(cos(radians(37)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(-122)) + sin(radians(37)) * sin(radians(lat)))) 
                           AS distance 
                           FROM markers 
                           HAVING distance < 25 
                           ORDER BY distance 
                           LIMIT 0 , 20
                    ";
                $search_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query, $distance);

                if (!$search_query) {
                    die("QUERY FAILED" . mysqli_error($connection));
                } else {
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query)){
                        $name = $row['name'];
                        $address = $row['address'];
                        $city = $row['city'];
                        $state = $row['state'];
                        $zip_code = $row['zip_code'];

                        echo "<h4>$name</h4>";
                        echo "<p>$address</p>";
                        echo "<p>$city, $state, $zip_code</p></br>";
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the SQL are you attempting to run? (some idea whats in the db & the wider code may also help people answer)

Comment: `mysqli_query()` takes 2 arguments, not 3. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php edit: just as Phiter noted below.

Comment: It can take 3 arguments, but the third must be an integer. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-description

Comment: nice idea, for upcoming version.. :)

Comment: You're either executing `$query` or `$distance`, not both.

Comment: you're looking for a multi-query most likely

Comment: @PhiterFernandes good point on that.

Comment: Looks like you could combine those two queries. Just add the WHERE clause from `$query` to the `$distance` query.

Comment: Or depending on how it's executed, it might be better for `$query` to be a subquery of `$distance`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run multiple queries in `mysqli_query()` as you're doing.

Also, the third argument of the function cannot be a string, as given. It must be a integer.

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-description)

```
mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

> **resultmode**
>
> Either the constant MYSQLI_USE_RESULT or
>   MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT depending on the desired behavior. By default,
>   MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT is used.
>
> If you use MYSQLI_USE_RESULT all subsequent calls will return error
>   Commands out of sync unless you call mysqli_free_result()
>
> With MYSQLI_ASYNC (available with mysqlnd), it is possible to perform
>   query asynchronously. mysqli_poll() is then used to get results from
>   such queries.

You can run two `mysqli_query` and treat them individually.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks for letting me know. I will try using one query.

Answer (score 0):

As others have correctly stated, you can't pass two separate queries to `mysqli_query` like that. But it doesn't look like you should be executing two queries anyway. You can combine both of them into one.

```
$query = "SELECT id, (big ugly formula) AS distance
          FROM markers 
          WHERE zip_code LIKE '%$search%'
          HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20";

$search_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

A couple of things about this:

This will exclude locations that *are* within the specified distance if they are not in the same zip code. (I assume that's what you wanted, but I'm not sure why.)

This query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Rather than concatenating `$search` into the SQL string, you should [bind](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) it to a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Thanks for all the feed back. I tried combining them into one statement but I keep getting errors. The big ugly formula was one that I found that calculates distance between two points using longitude and latitude. Is there an easier way to figure out location from user's input and then find the closest store based on user location? That's what I'm trying to do but I keep running into walls. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that there was anything _wrong_ with the big ugly formula. I omitted it and used a smaller placeholder because I thought the question wasn't directly about the formula, but more about the problem with the PHP implementation. It looks like a reasonable distance formula to me. Are you getting errors from PHP or MySQL?